# convert SqlByte datatype to byte in c#

Tags: c#

when i try to convert the SqlByte datatype to byte like this:

```
    SqlByte x = 2;
    int y;
    y = Convert.ToInt32(x);
```

this exeptions happens: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlByte' to type 'System.IConvertible.`

how can convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SqlByte x = 2;
int y;
y = (int) x;
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent type of a `SqlByte` is a `Byte`. Hence you can't convert it to an `Int32`.

Furthermore the actual connection is the following:

- The Sql Server Data Type is `tinyint`.
- The CLR data type (SQL Server) is `SqlByte`
- The CLR data type (.NET Framework) is `Byte`